# How to add some text to end of document title with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, title

I have basic html like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page name @</title> 
</head>
</html>
```

After "@" thing I need to have domain name ("EKS.RU"), and I think that JS is best solution for that problem.

So if I need to change domain I need to simple edit part of text in one script file.

Comment: You can use `document.title` to get and set the title on a page.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.title` to **get** and **set** the page title, so for your case you can do something like this.

```
document.title += "EKS.RU";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to do this indeed, All you got to do is find the title attribute, and then add to it's text `window.location.hostname` which will returns the domain of the page.

```
document.title += window.location.hostname;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy with document.title:

```
var domain = 'your.domain';
document.title += domain;
```

Just change the domain variable to whatever you want. Also make sure to place this in a script tag, right before the closing body tag, in case you add other code to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append value like:

```
document.title += "this text added at the end of title";
```